# Please help! Employer coerced me signing a backdated commission agreement, threatening to withhold earned commissions if I didn’t. What can I do?

Tags: management

My corporate organization is a mess. Here is the high level:

- 4 commission agreement changes in a year
- I’m the top salesperson
- They’ve underpaid my commissions multiple times, I’m patient with them fixing it, I know they’re growing
- presented with another new commission agreement and told to sign it within two days OR back pay commission they discovered of over 20k+ from the whole year to date wouldn’t be paid.
- I was not given enough time to have my personal attorney review this legal agreement and was coerced to sign it with 20k+ in unpaid being held over my head
- I told them in writing I needed time for my attorney to review, their response was ‘if you don’t sign it, we will not pay you the 20k+’
- While this is occurring, they changed my title-it is a demotion in title, but they insist it’s not a demotion, in writing, because they gave me a raise while giving me a lower ranking title.
- I’ve been told for the last 5 months I was not demoted, that it was just a title change
- Out of nowhere this last week, the new GM told me in writing the reason I had a title change 5months ago was my old role was ‘eliminated’ that there are no more directors at our company (there are 4 of them, actually) - this message came out of nowhere, did not come from hr and no one has ever once mentioned that before this week.
- I’m a consistent over performer, earning much more than most managers in the organization, was hired as a director, but still also held the highest quota of anyone on our team

My question: I love my industry and have a substantial network and many years invested, if I leave this large corporation, people will know and they will ask, what can I do to make sure I leave with my head held high - if I sue, people in our tight knit industry will know.

Comment: OK, so things are badly screwed up - but what's your actual goal here? Do you want your 20k, do you want your old title back or do you just want to drop a large rock on them from a great height?

Comment: Such a great question! Can I say all? I’ve been so patient and they know that at the C-level, the middle management layer is a disaster. I want my 20k of course, but needed time to have an attorney review the new legal agreement before I signed it, they wouldn’t give me that time, and the title I was hired to do, I’m damn good at, and they know this also, I get the sense I’m ‘making too much’ and they’re trying to adjust, however that impacts my career trajectory deeply. I have no ill will and have been so patient for too long - so dropping a large rock is starting to sound promising.

Comment: You _can_ say "all", but to some extent you have to prioritise - or at least categorise things into "annoying but I can live with it", "I'll find another job if they don't fix this" and "I will take legal action if they don't fix this". All are options, but only you can say which ones fix into which categories.

Comment: The backdated agreement was signed two weeks ago by me and was backdated to January 1, making it technically the 4th commission agreement since March 2021, so 4 of them in 9 months, likely because I keep crushing all sales goals substantially. My bigger challenge though is I’m in an insistent I absolutely love and I have a non compete also, making it impossible to go to a competitor for a year after I terminate - but they’re making it so painful to want to stay here. They gave me a raise in March to keep me, as they know I’m being shopped by many others in our industry.

Comment: Philip that’s such great advice - I can say with clarity, the fact that I’m up at 3:40am writing a question on a forum I’ve never before visited, this situation gives me deep anxiety that is becoming difficult to contend with. I don’t want to sue anyone, but I’m frustrated I’ll be forced to find a role with a company that takes deeper care of their hard working employees and cultures, and will have a non compete to contend with. I’ve spent years building my network in my industry. It’s a heartbreaking thought to have to leave it for a year while a non compete runs out. Rock hard place.

Comment: So leave, ignore the non-compete saying you won’t sue them over the commission crap…

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I very strongly agree with Gregory.  Since you have a personal attorney – as every wise person *should* have – you should **immediately** consult with him or her and ask for *qualified* advice.

As a *layman,* it seems very likely to me that certain labor laws have been broken here, but only your **counselor** (or his/her specialty delegate) is truly qualified to answer, and to advise you. Don't seek potentially-legal advice from an internet forum when you have an existing relationship with someone who *actually knows* or can find out.  Someone whom you already trust.

Sometimes, a simple letter written on a counselor's official letterhead can do wonders . . .  "Bow of ship. Cannonball. Or just the fact that there's a cannon out there."

I first met my attorney, "Tom," when my wife and I had to probate a slightly-difficult will.  He provided superior service at a very reasonable rate, and took the time to carefully answer all of our questions.  Our business relationship with him very quickly matured to the point where I now very-regularly say, *"let me ask Tom ..."*  He is our implicitly-trustworthy **counselor,** right there on my speed-dial.

Since you also have one, wise person, do the same without delay.

Answer (score 11):

Because you have a personal attorney, the best thing you can do is have a conversation with them.

While this situation is undeniably stressful, their prolonged inaction in keeping up their end of the contract, along with their (apparently unlawful) coercion into making you sign a new contract, is likely to give you an escape from the non-compete.

A court would untimely decide if you have unfairly breached your contract, and their inability to pay you what you are owed and them acting in bad faith, is likely enough reason for you to be able to go elsewhere without them considering going to court.

But as I said, you need to speak to your personal attorney because there are a range of factors at play, and they will be best-placed to know what your options are.